# Mobile accessibility - Talkback gestures not consistent across devices

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

Am testing  accessibility for android devices using various gestures available here in https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/2926960?hl=en

But in firefox , for the Google search page gets loaded and swipe with one finger takes to all the options in the taskbar but further swipes not taking me to the google logo and other contents.

But if i do swipe up down in one motion and then swipe with one finger successive items are getting read by talkback. Am also not hearing screenreader giving feedback on "read by character" or "read by word" gestures given in the above link(refer the above link for the gestures )

so the question is do others are also having the same inconsistencies with the gestures in android 4.1 jellybean nexus 7 ?

Also please share your experiences with android devices?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, TalkBack mostly only allow swipe navigation on the taskbar option rather than both the taskbar and the Web view contents if your web page is already loaded before you turn TalkBack on.

To prevent this from happening, I usually turn on TalkBack first before I open any web pages in Google Chrome browser.